# Delphi platform error on Hewlett Packard customized OEM Windows

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

I keep getting the same error setting up my computer so it will run Delphi, I've already set up a user override on the `PLATFORM` environment variable, to convert it to win32 but it's still giving the same error;

> [Error Error] Invalid PLATFORM variable "HPD". PLATFORM must be one of the following: "Win32", "Win64", "Android", "iOSSimulator", "iOSDevice", or "OSX32". If PLATFORM is defined by your system's environment, it must be overridden in the RAD Studio IDE or passed explicitly on the command line to MSBuild; e.g., /p:Platform=Win32.

Can anyone explain why it's doing this and how to fix the error?
The fact that I was working in Delphi XE2 in college and I'm using Delphi XE3 now may affect this

Comment: The error message contains the solution itself.. what part you don't understand? What are you doing when the error raises? (sorry, but "setting up my computing A2 coursework" is not widely known, so I have no idea if you're compiling a project, starting the IDE or what?)

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=Platform=HPD&sourceid=opera

Top results shows that the problem is using Hewlett Packard machine and their customized Windows configuration. Either reset it to vanilla windows or override it in Delphi Tools/Options menu

Comment: Compiling a project that compiled properly on a college computer, but wouldn't compile on my home computer, solved now by deleting the system's platform variable

Comment: I edited the question to make the first sentence clearer to other people who have no idea what your "A2 thingy" is.  You may notice that other people in the world are not at your school and don't use your terminology. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably using an HP computer. They come pre-configured with a `PLATFORM` environmental variable.

The newer XPlatform versions of Delphi use the `PLATFORM` variable to track what the target build is for (`WIN32`, `WIN64`, `ANDROID`, `iOSSimulator`, `iOSDevice`,or `OSX32`). Since there's already one there, it's trying to use it, but can't figure out what to do with a target of `HPD`.

The easiest way to fix this for all your projects is to go into your computer's settings (right-click `My Computer` on the desktop or Start Menu, `Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environmental Variables`, and just delete the `PLATFORM` variable. (HP doesn't seem to use it for anything, and I've done this on half a dozen computers with no ill effects.)

Comment: Thanks for that, took the advice and it runs perfectly now

Comment: Thanks, I was changing it by hand, worked but tedious. Didn't know it was save to delete. Deleting makes things compiling again.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem (see for example  [Chris Rolliston's blog](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/xe2-or-more-exactly-msbuild-vs-hp-notebooks/)) with HP computers - they do set up a system environment variable called `PLATFORM` which conflicts with the parameter expected by `MSBuild`. Solution is to delete the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for that, took the advice and it runs perfectly now