# Nested static libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

I have a static library for a `Vector` implementation in C.

I am now making a new library that is going to rely on the `Vector` in order to function property. This new library is called `String`. Both are static libraries created in Visual Studio with their own `.c` and `.h` files.

I do the following just like I would when referencing any other static library

- Create new static library. Create `.c` and `.h` files in it.
- `project -> properties -> C/C++ -> Additional include directories` and set as the folder that contains the `.c` and `.h` files for my `Vector`
- `File -> Add -> Existing Project` and set the `.vcxproj` file of the `Vector` project.
- In my solution explorer, I went under my `String` solution and right clicked `References` and then check-marked the `Vector` box that shows up.

At this point, my `String` is now correctly able to see `Vector`.

**The problem**

When I open a new project, repeat those same steps except with `String` as the target library, I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB8006 The Platform for project 'C-DataStructuresLib.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='HPD'. This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Platform.    CStringLib  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets    21
```

The line:

> This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Platform

Is correct because that's exactly what I'm trying to do. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Plenty of Google hits for this error, crystal ball says that you have a Hewlett Packard desktop (HPD) machine.

Comment: [Indeed so](http://i.imgur.com/WXPNd5u.png). Mind providing me with a link  to any information you found? My google fu is decent but I didn't find anything helpful online

Comment: Just query for "platform hpd invalid".

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe the platform has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: try to use CMake with visual studio

Comment: Did you try the accepted [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787472/delphi-platform-error-on-hewlett-packard-customized-oem-windows)

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to compile as 64-bit project?
Check in the property page the section: Linker -> Advanced -> Target Machine